# During "partial panel" flying, in what ways is a turn rate indicator more useful than a turn coordinator?

Tags: flight-instruments, gyroscopic-instruments

This question deals with flying by reference to old-fashioned "steam gauges", not a modern "glass cockpit".

I recall hearing some pilots very experienced (ATP) pilots advocate for the older-style "turn rate indicator" (senses rotation about the aircraft's up/down axis) over the newer-style "turn coordinator" (senses rotation around an axis canted about 35 degrees from vertical, to sense roll as well as yaw.)  Specific reasons were given, but I don't recall them. In what ways is a turn rate indicator more useful than a turn coordinator, during "partial panel" flying (no working attitude indicator or heading indicator) in clouds?

The purpose of canting the gyro's axis of rotation to sense roll as well as yaw is to give an earlier warning to the first stages of a developing bank and turn, and in my experience this is indeed helpful, but apparently there are some drawbacks as well.

Comment: There is some related content in this answer -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/81919/34686

Answer (score 8):

A turn coordinator's axis of rotation is tilted around 30 degrees and rotates in the opposite direction. Because of this, looping errror is reversed and it under-reads at more than 1g. This makes it essentially useless when recovering from an unusual attitude on instruments, which is one situation in which you can easily find yourself when flying partial-panel.

With a turn rate indicator the instrument will over-read when the pilot is pulling excess G's in a turn; all the pilot has to do is relax the backpressure on the stick or yoke to correct.

Comment: Well, I can say in the situation where I really really wished I had a working turn rate indicator or turn coordinator, there was definitely a strong G-load.

Comment: Re the effects of "looping error" in the turn rate indicator versus the turn coordinator-- Is it really inherent in the concept of tilting the gyro axis to sense roll as well as yaw, that the gyro must spin in the opposite direction in the (canted) "turn coordinator" as in the (non-canted) "turn rate indicator"? If so, why?  And if not, why did the designers of the turn coordinator choose to do this?  Perhaps this would be appropriate as an actual question.

Comment: Re the concept of "looping error", this post may possibly be of some interest-- apparently if the springs that try to hold the gyro axis fixed relative to the aircraft are stiff enough, "looping error" can be greatly reduced-- https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/528255-turn-rate-indicator-turn-coordinator-looping-error.html?highlight=turn+rate+indicator+turn+coordinator+looping+error#post8337851

Comment: Never mind my comments about the direction of rotation of the gyro of the Turn Coordinator-- I think what you describe may be the norm but apparently it is not *always* that way-- I made a new question about it -- https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/81983/in-various-different-makes-and-models-of-turn-coordinators-do-the-gyro-wheels/81988#81988

Comment: Care to comment on this answer -- esp if you have definite knowledge that some turn coordinator gyros do (or did) indeed spin CCW rather than CW as viewed from the right, i.e. opposite the direction of the gyro in a turn rate indicator?   https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/81983/in-some-turn-coordinators-does-the-gyro-spin-opposite-to-the-direction-it-spi

Answer (score 5):

You have the yaw/roll switched.  The TC's canted gyro adds roll to the yaw rate sensing, not the other way around.

The biggest drawback to the turn coordinator was the presentation of the aircraft, which to someone new to its use can tend to get mentally processed as a horizon bar, especially an old timer trained on aircraft with war surplus black face artificial horizons (with were widely installed on light aircraft into the 60s until surplus stocks ran out).  The TC's little airplane tilting left could initially be mentally interpreted as a bank to the right in other words, until your conscious brain finished processing the information (Russian artificial horizons had this presentation where the gyro tilted an airplane symbol; transitioning to western style horizons can be a problem for Russian pilots).

A turn and  bank with the vertical needle is easier to interpret at a glance.  The problem with the turn and bank was since only yaw rate information was presented, and there is no internal damping, in bumpy air you ended up with too much "noise" in the information presented from the nose wagging back and forth. In an airplanes like V tail Beech Bonanza, which were quite bad for tail wagging in turbulence, a regular turn and bank could be nearly useless in the bumps with the needle slewing back and forth constantly in level flight.  TCs avoid this by not just splitting the motion sensing between roll and yaw, but also by using internal dampers (little shock absorbers) to present only movement that is established.

One problem with TCs is that once you are stabilized in a turn, there is no more roll rate to sense, only turn rate and that has to be taken into account in the way the rate markings are placed.

My old '68 Cardinal had a TC that had gone bad because the internal damper had gone south.  The thing jumped around like crazy because of the un-damped sensitivity to both roll and yaw.  I replaced it with an older 12v electric turn and bank (way cheaper - Turn Coordinators are quite expensive because they are electric with internal inverters to convert 12vdc to 110v/400 Hz fixed frequency ac for the gyro) and found I had a strong preference for the vertical needle presentation.

Personally, I think the turn coordinator should have stuck with the vertical turn needle presentation, but with the damped canted gyro internals. Like I said, much easier to interpret at a glance.

Comment: Yes, thank you, re yaw/ roll switching

Comment: I definitely agree re ease of interpretation at a glance.

Comment: PS look at this piezoelectric turn rate indicator-- do you see the problem with the unmodified display on the left-- the pilot has to remember that the LED lights are supposed to represent the wingtips of the aircraft, NOT the horizon-- it is kind of backwards from a conventional "turn coordinator", which uses a somewhat similar display face.  The other device shown at the end of the video may be mounted either flat to sense pure yaw, or tilted to mix  roll sensing -- I prefer the latter.  https://vimeo.com/64331923

Comment: Yeah that's even worse, although he's invented a great gadget.  Imagine how instantly recognizable the indication would be with just a vertical pointer moving right for right turn and left for left turn.

Comment: You'd be the first person I know who prefers the vertical needle indication. The tilting airplane is much more obvious for interpretation, even if you don't know exactly what it means. But both are 'good' in the sense that to 'fix the problem', you counteract (oppose) the indication with the stick/yoke. That's how all indication should be, because in a stress we instinctively behave that way. This is why Russian pilots have big problems with the 'western' (direct) AI while western pilots never have problems with the 'Russian' (reverse) AI. (And why the @quiet's indicator is just horrible).

Comment: It's the fact that the turn needle presentation is more clear, enough that you can pick up movement of the needle in your peripheral vision.  Very few pilots have ever used an old style turn and bank as they are pretty rare now.

Comment: If you knew me, Zeus, then John K  would be the second as I agree w/ him.  One confusing thing about the turn coordinator is that the symbolic airplane tilts in the opposite direction as the horizon line on an attitude indicator, so a pilot who is used to mainly relying on an attitude indicator may tend to unconsciously interpret the tilting of something that looks sort of like a horizontal line (e.g. the symbolic airplane on the turn coordinator) as an indication of a bank in the opposite direction as actually exists.

Comment: Re comment above, I'm speaking from my real-world impressions practicing under the hood.  I see something tilting in the opposite direction as I'm used to seeing the horizon line of the attitude indicator tilt in the same situation, and I find it a little confusing.  That's my personal experience. I've also flown aircraft w/ the older style display and found it easier to interpret-- though again I'll say I did appreciate what seemed to me to be the larger initial indication for a given small initial roll rate away from wings-level, of the turn "coordinator" w/ canted gyro..

Comment: PS if you are flying an aircraft that typically experiences a great deal of adverse yaw as it starts to roll into a turn, that's when the benefits of the canted gyro axis really hit home.  Piezoelectric sensors don't suffer suffer from the G-loading issue described in another answer so if that's what you are using then you eliminate that potential drawback.  Sorry getting a bit off track from the original question here.

Comment: @John, very few, really? In all the airplanes I flew (which are mostly single-engine Cessnas and Pipers, i.e. not particularly new, but that's perhaps a dozen airframes) I remember seeing the vertical needle only once.

Comment: @quietflyer, I trust you, and I admitted the combination of this indication with the conventional AI (horizon) may be confusing. But in an ideal world, we would be changing the AI indication. Enough research have been done to prove that the reverse indication is better.

Comment: Interesting- I never thought of that.  What, the plane moves an the horizon stands still?  Like you are flying an RC plane?  Wouldn't some people find that confusing when inverted?  I guess nothing is actually reversed while inverted so...

Answer (score 1):

Some other reasons a turn coordinator is less useful than a turn rate indicator--

- Due to the fact that the axis of the gyro is canted to sense roll as well as yaw, a turn coordinator cannot be calibrated to read accurately for all combinations of airspeed and bank angle.
- In an inverted spin, the direction of roll is opposite the direction of yaw, so a "turn coordinator" with the canted axis of sensing may either give an indication of a turn into the direction of spin, or the opposite. For some discussion of this see https://www.pprune.org/archive/index.php/t-56241.html